# Is it a way to restore private key from 12-phrase?

Tags: copay

I can not restore my wallet from Copay even though I have the 12-word. Is it a way to convert back 'manually' with an other external solution and get the private key? Is the 12-word key storage a universal thing, or only `Copay`, `Bitpay` uses it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can restore your wallet using another external solution called Exodus.

You can find a step by step process here: [How do I restore from my 12 Word Phrase?](https://support.exodus.io/article/42-how-do-i-restore-from-my-12-word-phrase)

I hope it helps you.

There are some other ways as well, I will keep this answer updated.

Comment: Wow, I tried to restore with Exodus, and 0.00 BTC exist on the BTC wallet, and no transaction found. How is it possible? I am sure I copy pasted the right 12 words.

Comment: Can you share your wallet address?

Comment: Here it is ;) https://blockchain.info/address/16t3ikwNWgkUhsoSi8SCeG7BmqmQf8iwJn

Comment: When you restored with Exodus, does that showed the same address as you have given above? If not, then you have the wrong 12 word phrase probably mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you are experiencing issues restoring your BitPay or Copay wallet with your 12 word recovery phrase, please check the following:

- Are you sure that the recovery phrase was written in the correct order?
- Did you use all lowercase letters and no punctuation?
- Did you add a password to your recovery phrase?
- [Do you have the QR code or text/file backup?](https://support.bitpay.com/hc/en-us/articles/115003004363-I-lost-my-wallet-or-changed-my-phone-What-can-I-do-to-restore-my-wallet-)
- Did you separate each word with a single space (no commas or any other punctuation)?

Please also ensure that your words are all contained in the following list of possible words:
https://github.com/bitcoin/bips/blob/master/bip-0039/english.txt